# Store an image in disk

Tags: printing, image, scanning, compression

I have a 1x1 inch passport photo and I want to store it in a computer disk in a way I minimize the size but also been able to print it back to the real world.

What do you recommend me? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** this question is about image resolution.

Comment: It's kind of a vague question, possibly not related directly to programming.  What does your application do?  If this is just a general computer question, it might be better to ask it on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database, consider storing the image in a BLOB column, that will allow you to relate it with other information.